# Using a Facebook Image from a Tweet

Tags: python, facebook, twitter

For an app I am currently working on I am pulling in tweet objects with the Twitter Python wrapper. If a tweet has an image, I am pulling out that image URL and passing it into an  in a template to display the image. If a tweet object has an image that is has a twitpic or instagram URL, the URL passes into the source just fine, and the image displays correctly.

However, if a tweet object has an image from a facebook URL, the image is returned as broken. This seems to be because the facebook URL to the image is actually a URL to the post. Thus when you try to pass the URL into the image tag, it returns a broken image because the URL is not actually for an image, its for a facebook post. So my question is this: How can I extract the image URL from the facebook post so I can pass that into my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Facebook Graph API to query for that page or try to pull an automatic picture

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer